# O que fazer com usuário que edita para ganhar reputação?

Tags: debate

Ultimamente tenho percebido um número absurdamente grande de análises de edição, e para minha surpresa a absurda maioria destas análises vem do mesmo usuário.

Algumas destas edições são feitas de forma errônea, aparentemente com o objetivo de editá-las novamente para ganhar mais reputação.

Existem muitas edições que não melhoram nem a compreensão da pergunta nem a legibilidade da mesma, são apenas formatação básica do texto ou do código e mesmo assim elas são aceitas

As especulações que faço se dão ao fato de a maioria dos pontos obtidos por este usuário nos últimos dias terem vindo de edições e algumas vezes mais de uma na mesma publicação.

Como proceder?

Comment: Se as edições são úteis aceite se não rejeite.

Comment: Sim, as úteis eu aceito, mas exitem muitas que não fazem qualquer serviço em prol da pergunta e algumas são edições parecem ser errada propositalmente

Comment: Será que eu influenciei em algo? Será que também vão dizer que você esta fazendo falsas acusações por afirmar *"usuário que edita para ganhar reputação?"*?  Estranhamente aqui a pergunta parece ter sido bem aceita. Só pra constar, deixei +1 na sua pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tanto esta como a sua reflectem "processo/julgamento de intenção". Em ambos os casos("problemas") as ferramentas de moderação são suficientes para os resolver. Neste, se for verdade apenas a intenção de ganhar pontos, a rejeição continuada das edições irá resolver o "problema".

Comment: @ramaral então você esta presumindo que  limpar comentários e deixar pra lá é resolver algo? Você acha mesmo que todo mundo se preocupa com o ocorrido em todas tags, ou que um problema que já vinha se arrastando a meses e já foi reclamado teria solução, sério que você acredita mesmo que o problema lá ocorreu do dia pra noite e que nada mais além de abrir uma postagem no Meta foi tentando?

Comment: @ramaral Sério, eu acho que você não esta sabendo de fato o que ocorreu e acho que eu ter que ficar contando a historia toda não é necessário, pensava que eu era um usuário no minimo de confiança e que se eu falasse algo a minha palavra bastaria.

Comment: Estamos conversando com o usuário em questão no Chat. Ele se mostrou atencioso às observações feitas. Não vou citar o nome dele para evitar caça às bruxas, mas ele se mostra nas melhores das intenções

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O que eu quero dizer é que se as edições forem continuadamente rejeitadas um suposto usuário "cata-pontos" desistirá de as fazer.

Comment: @ramaral entendo, mas eu falei sobre a parte que você afirmou que a *ferramentas de moderação* já seria mais que o suficiente. Mas nem vou mais entrar nesses detalhes, infelizmente não serei capaz de explicar o ocorrido e porque cheguei a acreditar que o Meta seria o local ideal. Mesmo que eu fale talvez só vivenciando exatamente o mesmo. Até mais.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, apenas para constar, "As especulações que faço se dão ao fato de...", fiz questão de mencionar **especulações** para que sejam alvo de avaliação de um possível comportamento desviado.

Comment: @ErlonCharles eu não estou sendo contra ti, pelo contrário, é um apoio. É que eu fiz uma pergunta bem semelhante e usei um titulo bem parecido, todavia a minha pergunta foi levada como acusações e que o meu problema era algo pessoal com o usuário que estava fazendo mal uso de uma ferramenta. Tanto que lhe dei +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Para fechar/manter aberta uma pergunta são necessários pelo menos 3 votos. Apenas um usuário não consegue fazê-lo. Caso haja intenção "duvidosa" no voto e ela for continuadamente rejeitada o autor acabará por desistir. Eu julgo que as ferramentas de moderação são suficientes para resolver os **casos deste género**.

Comment: Boa tarde a todos! Sou quem esta editando as postagens. E novamente desculpe o transtorno. Eu deixei um +1! Vou buscar contribuir melhor com as edições. E mesmo quando não receber 'pontos' pretendo continuar contribuindo com as edições.

Comment: Procurei fazer perguntas, mas não foram muito bem aceitas .... mas isso é falha minha mesmo ..... porque as perguntas mais eram mal formuladas e confundiam. Enfim, assim a minha conta ficou sem como realizar perguntas, então, tenho que contribuir de alguma forma. E novamente desculpem pelo transtorno! E bom trabalho a todo!

Comment: E o motivo de a quantidade de edições ser grande é porque estou aplicando a [técnica Pomodoro](https://youtu.be/H0k0TQfZGSc) para me manter focado. Agora, que aprendi usar filtros nas perguntas, pretendo responder as perguntas sem respostas e inativas a mais de 6 meses ([java]Lastactive:2017-06-05 answers:0) mantendo o foco categorizando por assunto e focando nas perguntas.

Comment: @pss1suporte o mais importante de tudo é ser consistente, é ter certeza que a edição trará uma melhora na compreensão do seu conteúdo. Para pequenas correções você pode sinalizar a pergunta, ou resposta pra não monopolizar a *home page*. Não precisa se desculpar, nosso objetivo é evoluir a comunidade e infelizmente nem sempre me lembro que posso fazer sugestões pelo chat (em parte pq não gosto tanto da ferramenta de chat daqui, acho de difícil acesso). Bem vindo!

Comment: Eu acho que esta situação de edições massivas/caça pontos já se levantou várias vezes com alguns usuários, no curto espaço de tempo que por cá ando. Pessoalmente acho que um limite diário de edições para usuários com menos de 2k seria uma solução interessante, que provavelmente resolveria o problema.

Comment: Isso já acontece com votos, sinalizações, análises... Seria interessante.

Comment: @pss1suporte Embora vejo você editando bastante coisa, você não é o único usuário que tem se empolgado em edições, há outros também bem empolgados por aqui. De qualquer forma, contando que seja tomado o devido cuidado para não se cometer abusos e haja um verdadeiro empenho em se melhorar a qualidade, edições em massa são sempre bem-vindas.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, sim verdade! Hoje mesmo eu fui editar e foi rejeitada. Estou ficando mais criterioso por agora. Mas depois que passar dos 2k, fico mais tranquilo em edições triviais de formatação sem dar trabalho para os analistas. Então, tenho que trabalhar um pouco nas respostas para chegar no 2k!

Comment: @pss1suporte Se o seu problema é não poder postar perguntas novas porque as que você tem não foram bem aceitas, acabei de responder uma pergunta antiga sua para te ajudar, ainda mais considerando que, na minha opinião, a resposta que ela já tinha não era satisfatória. ;)

Comment: @VictorStafusa muito obrigado! E estou sem conta de votos!  E estou focado aqui em uma resposta aqui, mas assim que terminar retribuirei o favor! Muito obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Apesar de ter muitas edições do mesmo usuário, acho que o importante é analisarmos criteriosamente antes de aceitar, vi que muitas edições não estava melhorando a pergunta, por isso foram rejeitadas.

Comment: @LaércioLopes sim, as análises tem q ser feitas com mais critério, mas a questão é outra, como tratar com este usuário? Como direcioná-lo no melhor caminho com relação às edições? Como abordar? Como descobrir suas intenções?

Comment: @pss1suporte Muitas das suas edições são supérfluas, acho que até a maioria de 10 pra 8. E em todas vc coloca "melhorando a pergunta". Deveria especificar o que está alterando em cada edição, e não usar uma frase padrão.

Comment: @ÐvÐ, vou dar uma filtrada melhor com edições! Vou pegar postagens antigas! E agora que percebi que tenho como postar perguntas novamente! E novamente peço desculpas pelo trabalho e pelo transtorno! Estou querendo chegar logo nos 2K para poder editar sem preocupação de dar trabalho para os analistas.

Comment: @ErlonCharles, minhas intenções é colaborar com a comunidade! Estou querendo chegar logo nos 2K para poder editar sem preocupação de dar trabalho para os analistas. Tenho 3 anos que consumo o conteúdo do SOPT! E nunca contribui. Sei que tenho que fazer da melhor forma possível e pelo que estou vendo estou mais atrapalhando do que realmente ajudando! Mas novamente peço desculpas pelo trabalho e transtorno! Vou ser mais criterioso! **Mas não pretendo para de contribuir**!

Comment: @pss1suporte Não deve parar de contribuir não, amigo. ;)

Comment: @pss1suporte nem deve parar, o foco é melhorar a forma de contribuir, parabéns pelo seu empenho reputação é consequência da participação, tenho estado mais inativo na comunidade esse ano, mas contribuir pouco ainda é contribuir e sempre ajuda a fortalecer a comunidade, **Parabéns!**

Comment: eu sei que meu comentário meio que foge a esta discussão mas, o SO meio que força os usuários da plataforma a redigir um artigo acadêmico, muito minucioso, e eu acho isso intimidador para iniciantes, que ainda não tem experiência com programação, e nem mesmo em uso de uma plataforma com tantas regras como o SO, e sempre que venho ao meta, temo que isso fique pior.

Comment: Seu post me deu uma ideia de como ganhar pontos

Comment: @Khyser você pode sim ganhar pontos de reputação editando, apenas não abuse dessa ferramenta e faça edições que auxiliem na compreensão dos textos, senão elas serão negadas e você continuará sem pontos de reputação.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A edição em si não é problema, mesmo em quantidade. A não ser que sejam muito seguidas e monopolize a *home page*.

O abuso de edições **só** para ganhar reputação é. Podemos analisar se há abuso.

Editar piorando o conteúdo é bem ruim. Sempre que achar um caso assim sinalize para que os moderadores possam analisar individualmente. Se tiver várias sinalizações levantará outras questões sobre esta participação.

Isto obviamente não exclui a ação de rejeitar a sugestão de edição.

Existe um outro problema de pessoas que aceitam sugestões sem ler, só pra ganhar medalhinha. Precisamos saber quando percebem isto.

Comment: Ultimamente não estou muito ativo na comunidade, mas mesmo assim minhas últimas 6 análises de edição foram deste usuário e 4 delas foram rejeição e melhoria da edição.

Comment: Seria interessante analisar o usuário em questão pois o mesmo ocorreu comigo.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero, eu garanto de que não se trata de minerar pontos .... como comentei no chat noutro dia. É sou membro a mais de 3 anos e nunca contribui apenas consumo o conteúdo e as contribuições da comunidade. Agora estou empenhado em contribui.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero, procurei fazer perguntas, mas não foram muito bem aceitas .... mas isso é falha minha mesmo ..... porque as perguntas mais eram mal formuladas e confundiam. Enfim, assim a minha conta ficou sem como realizar perguntas, então, tenho que contribuir de alguma forma. E novamente desculpem pelo transtorno! E bom trabalho a todo!

Comment: @pss1suporte Não tenho certeza, mas editar provavelmente não lhe dará o direito de perguntar novamente. Tem que arrumar as perguntas problemáticas.

Comment: @pss1suporte meu comentário foi anterior a sua visita ao chat, lá você comentou conosco que queria contribuir para comunidade, fique tranquilo, está tudo certo ^^

Answer (score 4):

Tendo em vista o resultado da discussão, cheguei à conclusão que o melhor a se fazer é utilizar o [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=pt.stackoverflow.com) para chamar o usuário em questão, assim será possível analisar:

- O motivo de tantas edições
- O método que o usuário está utilizando para usar a ferramenta
- Passar recomendações sobre o uso do *SOPT*
- Passar recomendações sobre edições em perguntas e respostas

Comment: Não vai funcionar com todo mundo, claro que também concordo que seja o melhor, mas até o mais bem intencionado dos usuários as vezes é levado a mal quando só esta tentando instruir. Eu gostaria que uma houvesse uma auditoria sobre comportamentos, lógico que não seria pra levar tudo ao pé da letra, mas só pra conter alguns problemas significantes. Infelizmente nem todos se importam com isto e acabamos sendo considerados exagerados quando notamos algum problema. De qualquer forma essa parece a solução mais eficiente até o momento. +1

Answer (score 4):

Eu acho que editar muitas perguntas não é o problema, exceto, como disse o Maniero, em sequência de forma desnecessária, sem seguir as diretrizes já debatidas e recomendadas. É editar e não especificar o que está sendo editado.

Muitas vezes o editor coloca no motivo da edição uma frase padrão *"melhorando a pergunta"*. Sim, a intenção pressupostamente é melhorar, mas é preciso especificar "o quê" está sendo melhorado para que seja analisado pelo voto.

Outra coisa são edições supérfluas. Simplesmente mudar termos técnicos para itálico é um exemplo, como:

> No meu código HTML...

Editar para:

> No meu código *HTML*...

Não muda nada no entendimento do texto. São edições desnecessárias que não alteram a compreensão do texto.

Outra coisa é alterar e reescrever partes do texto com a própria redação do editor com o intuito de melhorá-lo. Se o AP não soube ser claro no seu texto, acho que ele mesmo deve melhorá-lo, exceto em casos específicos onde o editor pode mudar a posição de uma palavra ou pequenas partes afim de melhorar o entendimento.

Comment: É exatamente esses critérios que uso, e mesmo assim ontem um editor veio me criticar no chat dizendo que "eu não presto atenção no que edito", sendo que a edição dele melhora apenas o título de uma questão completamente confusa. Pessoal acha q botar estilização e consertar 1 problema quando se tem vários é suficiente.

Comment: tá aqui um exemplo
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262961/resgatar-dados-google-maps-api

Answer (score 0):

Eu ia abrir um tópico desse mas acabei achando aqui.
Também notei que a quantidade de edit é absurda, e como o LINQ comentou teve edição que colocaram texto em itálico ou negrito.. ou por exemplo:

Utilizei a função WriteLine()

Editaram para `WriteLine()`

Vi também edit em perguntas totalmente fora de escopo ou totalmente amplas.. é mais facil editar e ganhar +2 do que sinalizar né? :)

Sério.. não faz sentido, todas as vezes que eu edito as perguntas 90% é pra formatar código, adicionar tags úteis e principalmente ajustar o título para melhor entendimento pra quem está batendo o olho no feed principal.